# Python: parse html and produce a tabular text file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, text-files

**The problem:** I want to parse an html code and retrieve a file of tabular text such as this:

```
East Counties
Babergh, http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS297en-GB.xml, 876
Basildon, http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS109en-GB.xml, 1134
...
...
```

**What I get instead:**
Only `East Counties` appears in the txt file, so the for loop fails to print each new region. Attempt code is after the html code.

**HTML code:**
The code can be found in [this html page](http://view-source:http://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data/), of which this is the excerpt referring to the above table:

```
<h2>
                                    East Counties</h2>

                                        <table>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_titleLAName_0">Local authority</span>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_titleUpdate_0">Last update</span>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_titleEstablishments_0">Number of businesses</span>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_titleCulture_0">Download</span>
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_laNameLabel_0">Babergh</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_updatedLabel_0">04/05/2017 </span>
                                                at
                                                <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_updatedTime_0"> 12:00</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_establishmentsLabel_0">876</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_fileURLLabel_0" title="Babergh: English language" href="http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS297en-GB.xml">English language</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_laNameLabel_1">Basildon</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_updatedLabel_1">06/05/2017 </span>
                                                at
                                                <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_updatedTime_1"> 12:00</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_establishmentsLabel_1">1,134</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a id="listRegions_lvFiles_0_fileURLLabel_1" title="Basildon: English language" href="http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS109en-GB.xml">English language</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
```

**My attempt:**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data/'
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
mainpage = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(mainpage, 'html.parser')

regions=[]
with open('Regions_and_files.txt', 'w') as f:
    for h2 in soup.find_all('h2')[6:]: #Skip 6 h2 lines 
        region=h2.text.strip() #Get the text of each h2 without the white spaces
        regions.append(str(region))
        f.write(region+'\n')
        for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]: # Skip headers
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            if len(tds)==0:
                continue
            else:
                a = tr.find_all('a')
                link = str(a)[10:67]
                span = tr.find_all('span')
                places = int(str(span[3].text).replace(',', ''))
                f.write("%s,%s,%s" % \
                              (str(tds[0].text)[1:-1], link, places)+'\n')
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the *Beautiful Soup* library, but judging from the code it looks like in each `h2` cycle you are traversing all the `tr` elements of the document. You should instead traverse only rows that belong to the table related to the specific `h2` element.

**Edited:**
After a quick look at [Beautiful Soup docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways) looks like you can use `.next_sibling` since `h2` is always followed by the `table`, i.e. `table = h2.next_sibling.next_sibling` (called twice because the first sibling is a string containing whitespace). From the `table` you can then traverse all its rows.

The reason you are getting duplicates for Wales is because there actually **are** duplicates in the source.

Comment: Do you nest the search for `h2` inside that for `table`?

Comment: Solved the impasse. Thanks a ton!